# How to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{r^n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm a bit rusty on calculus and I'm not able to solve this rather simple limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{r^n}{n}$$
In my case $r = -1$, and "just by looking at it" I'd guess that for $\left|r\right| = 1, n \to \infty, \frac{\pm1^n}{n} \to 0$. But I was wondering if there's a general rule, since given values like $0.1, e, -2$ for $r$ the limit does not seem so obvious for me.

Comment: There is indeed a general rule.  The limit diverges for $|r|>1$ and converges otherwise.  Do you know L'hopital's rule?

Comment: ... converges otherwise to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: For $|r|\le 1$ we have

$$-\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{r^n}{n}\le \frac{1}{n}$$

and for $|r|>1$ the values $\frac{r^n}{n}$ are unbounded.

Comment: This really helps visualizing it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following theorem. Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence and let$$\ell = \lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$$
Then: $$\ell \in [0,1) \implies a_n\rightarrow0, $$

and $$\ell \in (1,+\infty) \implies a_n \rightarrow +\infty.$$
Note that the case $\ell=1$ doesn't tell you nothing. Examples: $$a_n=1,\qquad a_n=n.$$

Comment: How do you apply this theorem if $a_n=(-1)^n$?

Comment: Well, this doesn't work for the case $r=-1$. However, that's an easy one. This is a general rule as requested in the OP.